# I need Box shadow property like this button in react native

Tags: android, css, react-native

[image]I use this property but can not work

```
shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,

    elevation: 5,
```

Comment: Added an image I need that type of shadow

Comment: Do you use react-native button component?

Comment: @SDushan yes I am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-Native Button component doesn't have style prop. If you want to customize your button style you have to create a custom button using `TouchableOpacity` or `TouchableNativeFeedback`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>OK</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    width: '80%',
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#E13C17',
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  textStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFF',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Only working 'elevation' property but not working custom other property

Comment: @TusharKumawat shadow properties in react-native apply only on iOS. For Android, you should set elevation property in your view style.

Comment: you mean we can't use custom shadow in android?

Comment: @TusharKumawat check this - https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props